# CFDocument convert PDF to PDF/A format

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, pdfa

I'm converting an archive of documents (doc, docx, pdf, txt, rtf) to PDF/A using the CFDocument tag. It works for all types except for PDFs. For those the resulting file is corrupted and can not be opened. Since the CFPDF tag has no PDFA related attributes, I'm not sure what to do here.

I'm running CF 10 with the latest OpenOffice install on Windows 2003 Server.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the PDF/A format but the gist that I am getting from some searches is that those documents need to be 100% self contained so they can be reproduced accurately. That being the case it looks like you might be able to use the `optimize` action of the `cfpdf` tag to remove any links, javascript, etc. from your existing PDFs in an attempt to make them self contained. Not sure about the fall-out of losing formatting and such...

Comment: It's a fairly complex process to go from PDF to PDF/A. In most cases the file size doubles because it stores all fonts inside the document. I need it to actually be in this format, rather than simply behave as such.

Comment: Hmm... I know you can embed forms, but I am not sure cfdocument has any support for plain pdf=>pdf conversion (for lack of a better word). Have you looked into DDX? I believe LC can do it, so you might be able to use DDX (assuming the features required are not on the "disabled" list).

Comment: Looks like CF11 added and action="archive" option https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfpdf.html